# Dynamically allocating in main() VS in a funtion

Tags: c, dynamic

```
int foo(int *p){
    p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 20;
}

int main(){
    int a;
    int *x;
    x = &a;
    foo(x);
    printf("%d \n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

So I'm trying to point at `a` and then set the value of what `x` is pointing to 20. However whenever I allocate the pointer in the function I get a random number being printed. Do you know why this happens compared to allocating it in main()?
Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of `a`?

Comment: In order to write something into the variable x, you have to pass the address of x to the function. In other words: ``int foo(int **pp) { *pp =malloc(sizeof(int)); **pp = 20; } int main() { int *x; foo(&x);...}``

Comment: Isn't OP doing `int a; foo(&a); printf("%d \n", a);`?

Comment: Yes but I assumed this is nonsense and he really wants to know about the malloc, and the a- thing is an abberration :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to allocate in the foo function at all. This is like doing:

```
void foo(int p) {
    p = 2;
    printf("%d\n", p);
}

int main() {
    int a=1;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

And asking why it didn't print 1. The answer is, you're writing over the pointer to a, so you no longer have a pointer to a when you do `*p = 20;`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I just wanted to know why it works when i call malloc in the main vs it in the function. So's its because im overwriting it right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean because you haven't provided an example of what you mean by calling malloc in the main function. However in the case that you gave you are correct that it isn't giving you the expected behavior because you are overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm trying to point at a and then set the value of what x is pointing to 20

This doesn't make sense given the context of your question. You are pointing `x` at `a`, and if you want to change the value of `a`, then why are you dynamically allocating anything at all? `a` is already automatically allocated in `main()`. If you want to dynamically allocate something, what you you need `a` for at all?

To change the value of `a`, just pass a pointer to it and forget about `malloc()`:

```
void foo(int * p)
{
    *p = 20;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    foo(&a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to dynamically allocate, forget about `a`, and don't modify it through a passed pointer - return the pointer:

```
int * foo(void)
{
    int * p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if ( !p ) {
        perror("could not allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *p = 20;
    return p
}

int main(void)
{
    int * x = foo();
    printf("%d\n", *x);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: seriously ``exit()``? *the embedded embedded programmer inside me cringes*

Comment: I'm surprised the embedded embedded programmer inside you doesn't cringe a lot more at the idea of writing a program for an embedded device that `printf()`s `20` then terminates in the first place.

Comment: You need to take into account that some dude will copy your function into the code for the next mars rover mission and we will see the exit() call right 2s before the landing rockets are supposed to ignite...

Comment: @BitTickler: That's fine. Using `exit()` here is perfectly legitimate and normal. The alternative is what - returning `NULL` and immediately returning from `main()`? How is this better? It's exactly equivalent to the call to `exit()`. If someone writes bad code for the next Mars Rover, that's their problem and their employer's problem, not mine. Hopefully NASA isn't employing programmers who need to ask such questions on Stack Overflow, but that's their business. We should focus on real issues with real code, here.